# Uploading and displaying image in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have hard time uploading picture and then displaying it in my view. I went through a lot of posts here and for some reason nothing really works for me.

Picture gets uploaded (in my case saved in `~/Content/Images`, but is not displayed in the view. Whole project is published on Azure.

Please abstract from things like verifying if the uploaded file is really a picture or handling the size of the picture.

My domain model is:

```
public class Product
{
    ...
    public string ProductImageUrl { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Controller - post method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(/*[Bind(Include = "ProductId,ProductName,ProductDescription,ProductPrice, CategoryId, Quantity, picture")]*/ Product product, HttpPostedFileBase picture)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
        db.Products.Add(product);

        if (picture != null)
        {
             var originalFileName = Path.GetFileName(picture.FileName);
             string fileId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
             var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"), fileId + ".jpg");

             picture.SaveAs(path);

             product.ProductImageUrl = path;
             product.ProductImageName = fileId;

             db.SaveChanges();
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }

     return View(product);
}
```

My view is:

```
       @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="@item.ProductImageUrl" />
                </td>
...
```

Comment: you need to provide image type like .jpg or .png in the filename with guid and save it as well as in ProductImageUrl

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work

Comment: Can you check the request for this image in the network tab from the developer tools. That will most likely tell you why it is not showing.

Comment: @xcelm What is the Generated String of `item.ProductImageUrl` ?

Comment: @Valkyrie - product.ProductImageUrl = path;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that your are storing absolute path in the `ProductImageUrl` field and that's why its not working in your hosting environment. More importantly you don't need both `ProductImageUrl` and `ProductImageName` to handle images. Use only `ProductImageName`.

Do as follows:

Your `Product` model should as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    ...
    public string ProductImageName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then in the Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Product product, HttpPostedFileBase productImage)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      if (productImage != null && productImage.ContentLength > 0)
      {
          var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + "_" + Path.GetFileName(productImage.FileName);
          var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Product/"), fileName);

          productImage.SaveAs(path);
          product.ProductImageName = fileName;
      }

      db.Products.Add(product);
      await db.SaveChangesAsync();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }

   return View(product);
}
```

Then in the `View` as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
       <td>
           <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Product/"+@item.ProductImageName)" />
       </td>
   <tr>
}
```

Hope it will work for you! Thank you.

Comment: Great to see that it has solved your problem! Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `<base>` tag to your view so that all links are relative to your site. Then you don't need to build a path to the image at all.

For intance, if you site is at https://bestsiteever.com your tag would look like this:

```
<base href="https://bestsiteever.com" >
```

and your path would be:

```
$"/Content/Images/{fieldId}.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you post your image as a byte array, you should be able to turn it in Base64 format and display in view :

```
<img src="data:image;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.ProductImageUrl)" />
```

Worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong but the string stored in `item.ProductImageUrl` is a path like `c:\\..` right?

**Server.MapPath** gives relative hard drive location on the server. If you put that location in **src** then you are asking the browser to find that file in your **LOCAL** hard drive.

Try `item.ProductImageUrl = "<url to your site>/Content/Images/" + fileId + ".jpg";`.